# Symbol.iterator в ES6

Tags: javascript

Где-то еще кроме for..of и spread применяется кастомный итератор?

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

//итератор массива в обратном порядке
arr[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
 let currIndex = this.length;
  
  const that = this;
  
  return {
   next() {
     if (currIndex !== 0) {
       return {
         done: false,
          value: that[--currIndex]
        }
      } else {
        return {
         done: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.info('reduce');
const all = arr.reduce((tot, next) => {
 return tot += next + ',';
}, '');
console.log(all.slice(0,-1));

console.info('for..of');
let result = '';
for (let el of arr) {
 result += el + ',';
}
console.log(result.slice(0, -1));

console.info('forEach');
result = '';
arr.forEach(el => result += el + ',');
console.log(result.slice(0, -1));

console.info('map');
console.log(arr.map(el => el).join(','))

console.info('spread');
console.log([...arr].join(','));
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, он предназначен для `for..of`. Этого достаточно.

Где ещё? В `Array.from` вот тоже используется.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

//итератор массива в обратном порядке
arr[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  let i = this.length;
  return {
    next: () => i ? 
      {done: false, value: this[--i]} : 
      {done: true}
  }
}

console.info('Array.from');
console.log(Array.from(arr).join(','));

console.info('for..of');
let result = '';
for (let el of arr) {
  result += el + ',';
}
console.log(result.slice(0, -1));

console.info('spread');
console.log([...arr].join(','));
```

Comment: [@@iterator: A method that returns the default Iterator for an object. Called by the semantics of the for-of statement.](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#table-1)

Comment: Это в подтверждение: _предназначен для `for..of`_

Comment: спасибо, разобрался. Есть кстати библиотека функций высшего порядка для работы с итерируемыми объектами: https://fitzgen.github.io/wu.js/

@vp_arth в твоей редакции код гораздо аккуратнее выглядит